# Travis not caching directory

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I've got a .travis.yml file that is describing the directory to cache, however when I check the cache dropdown in travis, it tells me there is nothing. I'm just trying to cache my composer vendor folder. Below is my .travis.yml file:

```
sudo: required

language: php

php:
  - 7.0

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - docker-compose up -d

install: composer install
cache:
  directories:
    - root/vendor

script:
  - bundle exec rake phpcs
  - bundle exec rake phpunit:run
  - bundle exec rake ci:behat
```

And this is my project structure (or the folders/files that matter):

```
  |-- .travis.yml
  |-- root
    |-- vendor
```

Any suggestions as to why this would be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Old versions of Composer (pre alpha1) used `$HOME/.composer/cache/files` for caches, new versions use `$HOME/.cache/composer/files`.

Set the two of them for compatibility.

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.cache/composer/files
    - $HOME/.composer/cache/files
```

The Travis CI build log will print something along the lines of:

```
Setting up build cache

$ export CASHER_DIR=$HOME/.casher

$ Installing caching utilities                        0.05s
                                                      0.00s
attempting to download cache archive                  0.47s
fetching master/cache-linux-precise-xxx--xxx-xxx.tgz
found cache
                                                      0.00s
adding /home/travis/.cache/composer/files to cache  
adding /home/travis/.composer/cache/files to cache    1.28s
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to cache dependencies installed with `composer`, you need to specify your cache like this:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache
```

It's not the `vendor` directory that gets cached, but `composer`'s own cache.

However, you should also install from `dist` to keep the cache small:

```
install:
    - composer install --prefer-dist
```

For reference, see http://blog.wyrihaximus.net/2015/07/composer-cache-on-travis/.

Comment: Still not seeing a cache in Travis, this is my updated .travis.yml install and cache. I've also explicitly set sudo:false :

install:
  - composer install --prefer-dist

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache
    - root/vendor

Comment: Hard to tell without any further information. Is this an open source repository you can link to?

Comment: You should see something like this: https://travis-ci.org/localheinz/github-changelog/jobs/81238825#L85

Comment: Maybe caching doesn't work because you are using https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/.

Comment: Possibly -- there's nothing in their docs that explicitly say caching doesn't work with docker though

Comment: I'd get in touch with them, they're usually very helpful!